# How to handle HTTPS secure connection error in angular2?

Tags: angular, http, service, https, electron

[image: I already used this service angular2, now I cannot achieve this service even i gave everything as correct.]

I have already used this service with angular2, but now I can't even achieve the expected behavior when everything is correct.

Comment: Please add the code. The screenshot above doesn't look like an error.

Comment: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Comment: Your question doesn't really provide any information that would anyone allow to diagnose the problem. The question should contain the information required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think @GünterZöchbauer meant the code for the connection, not the error code. This would really help.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).